# HTML CSS How to drop caps words instead of just first letter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I asked a similar question for iOS NSAttributedString but since it's not possible with that, I am looking for a way to achieve this via HTML, CSS and javascript if needed.

I know CSS has "drop cap" using first-letter. Example: https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/GZxjEM

However, I need to do it for entire words and not just first-letter.
In the following picture, notice how "Strength" is the biggest and then "is not something" and "you have, rather" share the same line as "Strength".

**NOTE:** My problem isn't how to format the first word - it's how to have 2 lines share the first line. Notice how "Strength" is the biggest and then "is not something" and "you have, rather" share the same line as "Strength". How to make them share the same line? Similar to how drop-caps lets you have multiple lines be shared with the first letter.

I need to achieve a similar look with HTML, CSS and JS. If drop cap is not possible for this, is there any other way I can achieve this?

**NOTE:** Since my text will be variable, I can't use an image/photoshop etc.

[image]

**EDIT:** From suggestions, CSS Flexbox might be able to achieve this. I need to figure out how to place my words in the boxes:

[image]

```
    <div>
    <div style="float: left; font-size: 4em; background-color:grey;">
        STRENGTH
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px; background-color:yellow;">
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 2em;">is not</span><span style="font-size: 1em;"> something</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            you have, rather
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both; font-size: 2em;">
    something that reveals itself
</div>
<div style="font-size: 4em;">
    when you need it.
</div>
<div style="font-size: 1em;">
    #myHASHTAG
</div>
```

Comment: You should create a css class with `text-transform: uppercase` and put the word you want to uppercase in a `<span>` with the class to uppercase

Comment: Without more complex CSS which doesn't exist at the moment, you'll need to wrap each word in a `span` to then control the size and caps of the text.

Comment: Like this https://codepen.io/OliviaPaquay/pen/dRbbjz

Comment: @O.Paquay my problem isn't just the first word - it's how to have 2 lines share the first line. Notice how "Strength" is the biggest and then "is not something" and "you have, rather" share the same line as "Strength". How to make them share the same line? Similar to how drop-caps lets you have multiple lines be shared with the first letter.

Comment: You'll have to wrap your different lines in span and play with float to achieve this

Comment: @PranoyC you can use flexbox to achieve this.

Comment: @ArkadiuszWieczorek I edited the question with a picture of how I might be able to achieve this via flex box layout as per your suggestion. I apologize as I don't have experience with flexbox. You suggest that I can create a layout like my picture and then I can place my words in each of the layout boxes? Do you recommend any specific tutorials for creating this type of layout?

Comment: @PranoyC I can recommend [a guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [flexbox.help](http://flexbox.help/). ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a structure you can use, with Flexbox

```css
.inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.inner > div:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.inner2 {
  padding: 0 0 15px 10px;
}
.inner2 div:nth-child(-n+2) {
  display: inline-block;
}
.inner2 > div:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 28px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-child(3) {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div>Strength</div>
    <div class="inner2">
      <div>is not</div>
      <div>something</div>
      <div>you have, rather</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>something that reveals itself</div>
  <div>when you need it</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is perfect, thank you! a tiny nitpicking question: do you know if there is a way to align the bottom of "Strength" and "you have, rather"? Currently the "you have, rather" goes a bit below "Strength". I know my original image has that issue too but is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @PranoyC I already added the rule `.inner2 { padding: 0 0 10px 5px; }` to do that. Elaborate with the `10px` value to adjust from bottom and the `5px` from left

Comment: Ok I played around with it and setting it to 15px from bottom looks good. thanks, answer accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 20%;">
        Big Text
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 70%;">
        <div>
            small text first line
        </div>
        <div>
            small tex second line
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">
    the rest of the text
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work at all. It just places the words weirdly :(

Comment: @PranoyC Notice that I added the "clear: both". This should place the rest of the test beneath the first line. You should change the percentage from 20-70 to a one that will fit your text.

Comment: Thank you, I modified your solution a bit- instead of width, I used font-size. Seems to work well. Only problem now is that how can I make the bottom of the yellow part in this to be aligned with the bottom of the grey? https://jsfiddle.net/ff267gy2/2/

Comment: Try to give the yellow one a height, for example:  height: 72px;

Comment: @PranoyC the answer you accepted is just a copy-paste of my code that uses Flexbox, I think I deserve at least a little vote up. And BTW if your app should serve anyone else except for yourself I wouldn't use Flexbox because it's not supported in many many browsers, including all versions of Internet Explorer!!!

Answer (score 0):

I write an example for you and try to make it like the photo u share, hope it can be usefull for you :

HTML :

```
<span class="bigText">Strength </span>
<span class="mediumText">is not 
   <span class="smallText">something </span>
</span>
<span class="subLine">you have, rather</span>
```

css :

```
.bigText{
   font-size:80px;
   text-transform: uppercase;// use capitalize for make first word uppercase
 }  
.mediumText{
   font-size:30px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   position: absolute;
   top:35px
 }
 .smallText{
    font-size:20px;    
 }

 .subLine{
      font-size:20px;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/6o2fpf9t/1/